# Strange sidebar in iPhone app on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sidebar

In some cases, iPads display a small bar on the side of my iPhone app. I don't know what it is doing there or why. Been looking around for quite some time, but I can't find any information on the subject. May be I don't know what I'm looking for.

The problem is best described through a screenshot, here's a partial:

[image]

The grey bar is the problem. It appears out of nowhere and blocks a small part of the GUI. This screenshot is made with iOS 7, I have also seen it with iOS 6. On iOS 6, the bar is in a darker color, somewhat blackish.

Anyone familiar with this kind of issue?

Comment: check the subviews of window.

Comment: i also face the same issue just before couple of days. I get the array of subviews of window & get this gray subview at 3rd index. So, I make a loop & when get index three, then clear the color of that subview & solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, not really a solution to the problem, but a workaround. You also have no idea where this view comes from?